# Mulitiple instance from same usercontrol pass the values

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

There are 2 instances of the same user control. An event handler is attached on a button in the usercontrol.

I invoke the event handler from usercontrol_1, to show the value from usercontrol_1 in a textbox but both user controls show values in the textbox.

```
private void CalculatorInput_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InputBox.Text = "1";
}
```

Comment: Please show code for how you create 2 instances of the same user control, and how a button is placed in the user control.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned working with sender, but have you tried something like this:

```
private void CalculatorInput_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = sender as YourCustomControlType;
    if (control == null)
        return;

    control.InputBox.Text = "1";
}
```

Another good practice is, instead of exposing the control's child control (InputBox), create a public property on your control which gets/sets the text of that value, so your implementation code will look like:

```
control.DisplayText = "1";
```

And your control getter/setter:

```
public string DisplayText
{
    get { return this.InputBox.Text; }
    set { this.InputBox.Text = value; }
}
```